# iTextSharp - Printing Merged PDF Templates

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp in asp.net (C#) in order to merge more than one PDf template. There is a functionality of print which prints only data of the template. While merging the templates the fields/Controls which are available in the template is renamed using RenameField Method of iTextSharp. 
This implementation has broken the Print functionality. As the Print functionality has been written according to the fields.
For merging Templates, I am using a PDFCopy.

```
Document document = new Document();
bool flag = true;
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(newFile))
{
    PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, fileStream);
    PdfReader reader;
    MemoryStream baos;
    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
    {
        reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
        baos = new MemoryStream();
        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
        AcroFields pdfDoc = stamper.AcroFields;
        BuildData(datarow,pdfDoc, obj)
        renameFields(reader);
         stamper.FormFlattening = false;
         stamper.Close();
        reader = new PdfReader(baos.ToArray());
        copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, 1));
    }
    document.Close();
    strFileName = newFile;
}

private static void renameFields(PdfReader pdfReader)
{
    string prepend = String.Format("_{0}", counter++);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
    {
         pdfReader.AcroFields.RenameField(de.Key.ToString(), prepend + de.Key.ToString());
    }
 }
```

Edit1: This is the solution i found in itextsharp doc,BUT it's not working
"Using PdfCopy with documents
that have named destinations is one of these exceptions. All annotations, such
as link annotations, are kept with PdfCopy, but they no longer work for links to local
named destinations. There is a workaround for this problem."

```
PdfReader[] readers = {
new PdfReader(LinkActions.RESULT2),
new PdfReader(LinkActions.RESULT1) };
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy =
new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT1));
document.open();
int n;
for (int i = 0; i < readers.length; i++) {
readers[i].consolidateNamedDestinations();
n = readers[i].getNumberOfPages();
for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(readers[i], ++page));
}
}
```

Comment: Are you having a problem merging two pdf documents?

Comment: According to your description, there is something special about your templates. Their special printing functionality doesn't seem to get along with renamed AcroForm fields. Unfortunately renaming them is necessary if you want to merge multiple templates. Thus, you have to also adapt the printing functionality to the renamed fields.if you want to merge.

Comment: @thewisegod No i dont have problem with merging, after merging my action buttons are not working which is on the top of template.

Comment: For merging pdf, i have used PdfCopy and renameFields function, after that my link buttons are not working.

Answer (score 0):

The forms no longer work because you have forgotten to add a single line: `copy.setMergeFields();`

See the [MergeForms2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/MergeForms2) example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    copy.setMergeFields();
    document.open();
    List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(renameFields(src, ++i));
        readers.add(reader);
        copy.addDocument(reader);
    }
    document.close();
    for (PdfReader reader : readers) {
        reader.close();
    }
}

public byte[] renameFields(String src, int i) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>(form.getFields().keySet());
    for (String key : keys) {
        form.renameField(key, String.format("%s_%d", key, i));
    }
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

It seems that you're also making the assumption that your template consists of only one page:

```
copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, 1));
```

It is safer to add the document all at once:

```
copy.addDocument(reader);
```

**Important:**

My examples are written in Java. You are working with iTextSharp in C#. You will have to adapt the methods by changing the Java-specific methods into C#-specific properties or methods.

Comment: copy.setMergeFields(); is not working for me, and yes my template consist of one page and i am trying to fill it with different data in a loop.

Comment: I am using PdfSmartCopy to merge it and while merging i am renaming the fields.

Comment: So am I in the [`MergeForms2 `](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/MergeForms2) example, but I don't have any "Print" functionality. People on StackOverflow reading your question, don't know what you mean when you refer to your "Print" functionality, hence you shouldn't expect an answer that solves your problem is ["it doesn't work"](http://lowagie.com/doesntwork) is the only feedback you can give. Maybe you should show us the code of your "Print" functionality.

Comment: it's not about print functionality, it's all about the action button which is already present on the top of template.I don't know what functionality is written behind that, previously i was generating single pdf without using PdfSmartCopy and  renameFields() ,but now i have to merge multiple pdf. And in that case that ACTION button is not working. I have already shared the code.

Comment: I can't find the code of that ACTION button. If that code refers to a field named `myField` and if you change the name of that field to `myField1`, then **it should be obvious** that your ACTION button no longer works, because the code behind your ACTION button won't find any field with name `myField` anymore. I repeat: if you don't show the code behind the action button, then nobody can help you.

Comment: First of all thanks for replying. Sir, that action button is given in template and i dont have access to that template code, i need some workaround so that i can merge the pdf and also my action button should work. I found this on itextSharp document "Using PdfCopy with documents
that have named destinations is one of these exceptions. All annotations, such
as link annotations, are kept with PdfCopy, but they no longer work for links to local
named destinations." and they have given the solution

Comment: refer to Edit1 : for the solution provided in itextsharp document.

Comment: I don't understand: if you have the PDF, how come you don't have access to the action of the button? The action is inside the PDF as JavaScript code. Why wouldn't you have access to it? That would be very strange (even impossible).